# DataGridView carrega os dados mas não exibe eles

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Tenho um *DataGridView*, ele carrega os dados, mas não exibe eles.

```
private void AtualizarGrid()
{
    //Procura no banco os registro digitado na caixa de pesquisa.
    AlunoDAL alunoDAL = new AlunoDAL();

    //Exibi no Grid os nomes pesquisados no banco de dados.
    var bindingList = alunoDAL.CarregarAlunos();
    AlunosColecao alunosColecao = new AlunosColecao();
    var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);

    dataGridViewAluno.DataSource = null;
    dataGridViewAluno.DataSource = source;

    //Atualiza o Grid.
    dataGridViewAluno.Update();
    dataGridViewAluno.Refresh();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O nome das colunas estao iguais as colunas do datagridview? 
Por curiosidade debugando voce ve os itens dentro do source?

Comment: Sim estão iguais, sim debugando aparece os nomes, codigo etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução:**

```
public List<Aluno> CarregarAlunos(int ordernarPor = 0, string parametro = "")
    {
        // 0 id
        // 1 nome
        // 2 apelido


        List<Aluno> alunos = new List<Aluno>();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM alunos ";       

        switch (ordernarPor)
        {
            case -1:
            case 0 :
                {
                    if (parametro != "")
                    {
                        sql += " WHERE IdAluno like @parametro ";
                    }
                    sql += " ORDER BY IdAluno ";
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    if (parametro != "")
                    {
                        sql += " WHERE Nome like @parametro ";
                    }
                    sql += " ORDER BY Nome ";
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    if (parametro != "")
                    {
                        sql += " WHERE Apelido like @parametro ";
                    }
                    sql += " ORDER BY Apelido ";
                    break;
                }
        }           

        MySqlConnection conn = CriarConexao();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

        if (parametro != "")
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", "%" + parametro + "%");
        }


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
                aluno.IdAlunoP      = int.Parse( dr["IdAluno"].ToString());
                aluno.NomeP         = dr["Nome"].ToString();
                aluno.ApelidoP      = dr["Apelido"].ToString();
                aluno.SexoP         = dr["Sexo"].ToString();
                aluno.NascimentoP   = DateTime.Parse( dr["Nascimento"].ToString());
                aluno.CPFP          = dr["CPF"].ToString();
                aluno.RGP           = dr["RG"].ToString(); ;
                aluno.CidadeP       = dr["Cidade"].ToString();
                aluno.LogradouroP   = dr["Logradouro"].ToString();
                aluno.NumeroP       = dr["Numero"].ToString();
                aluno.BairroP       = dr["Bairro"].ToString();
                aluno.UFP           = dr["UF"].ToString();
                aluno.CEPP          = dr["CEP"].ToString();
                aluno.AdmissaoP     = DateTime.Parse(dr["Admissao"].ToString());
                aluno.TelefoneP     = dr["Telefone"].ToString();
                aluno.CelularP      = dr["Celular"].ToString();
                aluno.SituacaoP     = int.Parse(dr["Situacao"].ToString());

                alunos.Add(aluno);

            }
            conn.Close();                
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao Carregar Grid:" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
        }
        return alunos;            
    }
```